# Как мне на форме найти все пустые input?

Tags: html, css

Мне требуется на форме найти все пустые input'ы и обвести их красным цветом. Как это сделать?

Comment: Загуглите "валидация формы" и выберите подходящий для Вас вариант

Comment: Выбрать инпуты селектором, пробежаться циклом проверяя каждый на пустоту

Answer (score 1):

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]');
inputs.forEach(input => {  
  if (input.value.trim() === '')
      input.classList.add('error');
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: 1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value=""> 
<input type="text" value=""> 
<input type="text" value="2"> 
<input type="text" value="4"> 
<input type="text" value="  ">
```